# BibDesk Custom Template Condition Tag

Tags: bibliographies, msword, bibdesk

I'm using bibfuse to enable BibDesk to manage my references in Microsoft Word 2011. Using the BibDesk template tags (Apple's Key-Value Coding), I have the following template:

```
<$pubType=article?>
<$itemIndex/>. <$pubAuthors.unpunctuatedAbbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingTeX.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAndWithEtAlAfterThree/>. <$pubFields.Title.stringByRemovingTeX/>.<$pubFields.Journal/> <$pubFields.Year/>;<$pubFields.Volume/><$pubFields.Number/>): <$pubFields.Pages/>.
```

When the number of authors exceeds 3, the reference returned looks like this:

1. Wilcox AJ, Weinberg CR, O'Connor JF, et al.. Incidence of Early Loss of Pregnancy. New England Journal of Medicine 1988;319(4): 189-194.

Note the two periods ("et al.."). When the number of authors is 3 or less, the reference is correctly formatted, like this:

2. Regan L, Braude PR, and Trembath PL. Influence of past reproductive performance on risk of spontaneous abortion. BMJ 1989;299(6698): 541--545.

I'd like to know how to use BibDesk [condition tags](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDeskHelp_93.html) to omit the period after the `...AndWithEtAlAfterThree/>` if the number of authors is greater than 3. Note that this question was [asked and partially answered on the SourceForge mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/mailman/message/25605774/), but I still can't figure out how to implement based on the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [BibDesk Help: G. Template Tags](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDeskHelp_93.html), condition tags have the general structure:

```
<$conditionKey?>
template for non empty condition
<?$conditionKey?>
template for empty condition
</$conditionKey?>
```

One way to use condition tags to get the output you want is to use the *collection modifier key* `@fourthObject` on the *collection key* `authors` like this:

```
<$authors.@fourthObject?><?$authors.@fourthObject?>.</$authors.@fourthObject?>
```

We might translate this code into English as: "Is there a fourth object in the authors collection? If there is, don't output anything. If there isn't, output a period."

So, in your template, replace:

```
<$pubAuthors.unpunctuatedAbbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingTeX.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAndWithEtAlAfterThree/>.
```

with:

```
<$pubAuthors.unpunctuatedAbbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingTeX.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAndWithEtAlAfterThree/><$authors.@fourthObject?><?$authors.@fourthObject?>.</$authors.@fourthObject?>
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation/example. Worked like a charm! And it's just what I need to use condition tags more generally.